# Check if Exoplayer downloaded file is still available in storage

Tags: java, android, kotlin, exoplayer

I am downloading my HLS audio file using exoplayer and would like to know if file is downloaded. Exoplayer has given a way to check if file downloaded or not -

```
Download download = downloadManager.getDownloadIndex().getDownload(id);
return download != null && download.state != Download.STATE_FAILED;
```

It works fine in every cases except one of it. It detects if file is downloaded properly unless we manually go to the filemanager app and delete the downloaded files externally.

Is there a way to detect if the exoplayer downloaded file is still available in the storage. I have seen apps like Youtube which detects manually externally removal of exoplayer downloaded file.

Comment: It might be worth testing to see if this is a race condition - i.e. if the MediaStore manual deletion has not yet been updated or detected.

Comment: What I have observed from my testing and debugging, exoplayer maintains a seperate local database in which it stores the downloaded audio file details. And exoplayer checks if the audio file is presented in the local db to check if it is downloaded. So when we delete the file manually from file manager there is no way to remove the same object from exoplayer table.

Comment: Interesting - that sounds like it would be worth raising an issue on the ExoPlayer GitHub for.

Comment: @Mick Let me know if you open an issue